# msgpage C++ : send raw pointer with MSGPACK_DEFINE

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, stream, msgpack

I would like to send the following struct over msgpack.

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::string     name{""};
    int*            val{nullptr};

    MSGPACK_DEFINE( name, val );
};
```

Thus far in all of my projects, the only way I've streamed with msgpack is using MSGPACK_DEFINE, then writing the struct to msgpack::sbuffer (and sending it).  the MSGPACK_DEFINE macro complains that that perhaps I missed the "->" so I'm guessing it doesn't detect that it's a pointer.

Smart pointers seem to work though:

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::string          name{""};
    std::shared_ptr<int> val{nullptr};

    MSGPACK_DEFINE( name, val );
};
```

The caveat is that the receiver on the other end needs val to be a raw pointer.  I would like to do this without converting on the receiving side.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You failed to explain why you wish to do this. Pointers are never meaningful when serialized (otherwise it is in-process data and there is no need to serialize).

Just pass the value that the pointer points to.  If you need to represent "a number or NULL", then pass a struct containing an integer and boolean.

```
struct NullableInt {
    int value{0};
    bool null{true};
};
```

Comment: That was just a simple example.  In practice it's actually a pointer to other structs.  I'm sending a tree structure.  I'm fine with serializing it (somehow) but unaware of any msgpack macro that might work, or a way around it.  I think the answer is a simpler structure on the back end, and then do all the magic w/ the raw pointers on the receiving end.

Comment: Let me reiterate: pointers are never meaningful when serialized.

Comment: Let me clear this up: I'm wondering if the macro can dereference the pointer and serialize it for me in some meaningful way.  If it's wrapped in a shared_ptr, it works fine.

Comment: Ah.  Now I understand what you are after.  No, there is no support for raw pointers except in the case of char*.  You would need to extend MSGPACK with something like what is in adapter/char_ptr.hpp or adapter/cpp11/shared_ptr.hpp.